# Sudden increase in profile views without changing anything in profile. What could be the reason?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, views

I noticed a sudden increase in the number of profile views to my account.

I haven't changed anything in my profile.

Earlier it was like 2 or 3 in a week, but in the last 4-5 days it has been viewed 30-40 times.

What can be the reason for it?

Comment: We're watching you ...

Comment: People came across some good posts of yours and checked your profile.

Comment: @Bart: I don't think I had any objectionable thing in my profile. To keep an eye 3-5 times makes sense but 20-30 times, I can't understand.

Comment: Just kidding @DigvijayYadav. Sometimes posts make people interested in who is answering. It happens. And posting on Meta will add to that. Nothing special, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that should be a great shock for you.

People might have come across some posts and might have tried going to your profile. After this question you might have gotten 5–10 more views on your profile just to check what your profile view count is now.

Possible reasons would be:

1. You posted an answer or question and the viewer went to your profile to know more about you, like your previous stats.
2. People might have tried checking [the Users tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users), and there they might have found a new user and checked your profile.

The community actually pays some more attention to new users, not because they're spying on you, but just to keep the community the way it was meant to be.

Nothing else. It's not a big deal. Post good stuff, and you'll reach more views. But remember, they don't have a badge for that :-P

Comment: Thanks @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan to clearify all my doubts.